# Ferramentas para desenvolvimento mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone

Estou a procura de ferramentas para desenvolvimento *mobile*. Comecei a olhar uma chamada [CodenameOne](http://www.codenameone.com/), por exemplo. No entanto gostaria de umas dicas sobre qual ferramenta escolher.

Separei abaixo alguns critérios que eu gostaria que as ferramentas atendessem.
Peço que se tiverem boas escolhas que atendam a todos os requisitos me deixem como resposta (como acho que não serão muitas que passarão nos critérios, a resposta é finita).

1. Seja grátis.
2. Consiga fazer *deploy* para Android, iOS e Window Phone
   (e se possível também para outras plafatormas).
3. Utilize a linguagem Java
   (e/ou linguagens client-side como HTML5 e JavaScript).
4. Tenha bons simuladores
   (e que de preferência não sejam tão pesados).
5. Seja robusta, permitindo fazer jogos  complexos
   (mas também jogos simples, como o Flappy Bird).
6. Esteja em constante desenvolvimento e que seja amplamente usada por desenvolvedores de jogos mobile.

Comment: Para quem está pensando em fechar a pergunta, poderia dar uma lida nisto antes:  http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488/gorilla-vs-shark Pode confirmar ou mudar de ideia.

Comment: @bigown excelente texto, se tivesse lido isso no começo, algumas perguntas minhas não teriam sido fechadas. Em relação a pergunta, é ampla demais, é questão de ir ao google, vai surgir muitas opiniões, basta ler, decidir qual usar e começar a experimentar... só você poderá responder.

Comment: Mais duas leituras recomendadas para quem está fechando esta pergunta: *[Muitas perguntas estão sendo fechadas sem critério?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278/muitas-perguntas-estao-sendo-fechadas-sem-criterio)* e *[Devemos aceitar questões de recomendação?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-questoes-de-recomendacao)*

Comment: Obrigado pessoal pelos textos de apoio.

Answer (score 7):

**Qt Framework**

Como tenho mais experiência com essa e não posso falar de outras sem ter testado, posso sugerir o framework **[Qt 5.2+](http://qt-project.org/)**. Ele atende bem alguns dos casos que você citou, mas não todos. No entanto, vou cita-lo para agregar a pesquisas futuras.

1. O Qt está disponível na licença LGPLv2.1 (que pode ser utilizada para fins comerciais). Além da GPLv3 (open source) e também possui uma licença comercial (que permite link estático, suporte e etc).
2. Atualmente, para desktop o Qt suporta Windows, Linux, Mac OS X e Solaris. Já para mobile, suporta Android, iOS e, a partir da versão 5.3, Windows Phone 8. Parece que também estão trabalhando no suporte ao Tizen. Além desses, você pode desenvolver para [BlackBerry](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/dev/javascript/index.html) e [Ubuntu Mobile](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/) reaproveitando muito do código.
3. Essa é a parte que mesmo atende aos seus requisitos. As linguagens utilizadas pelo Qt para mobile são C++ e QML. Sendo que a maior parte do trabalho é possível fazer com o QML (parte gráfica, logica mais básica). No entanto, QML nada mais é do que uma mistura de JavaScript com uma pegada de CSS. Então, se você sabe JavaScript e CSS, não tem dificuldade.
4. Os simuladores dependem da plataforma para a qual você está desenvolvendo. Então isso não depende da ferramenta. No entanto, uma coisa que se pode fazer com o Qt é compilar para PC e testar modificações menores nele, o que é muito mais rápido. Assim, você só enviará o app para um emulador ou para o dispositivo quando quiser ver o comportamento real.
5. Pelo menos para desktop o Qt é completo, possui uma biblioteca bem grande e é bem documentado. Apesar de funcionar a base de OpenGL (usando ANGLE para WP), não sei se é viável para fazer jogos complexos pois as ferramente disponibilidades são claramente focadas no desenvolvimento de aplicativos e no máximo jogos 2D. Eu acho que o ideal é utilizar algo específico se o objetivo for jogos mais complexos.
6. O Qt está em desenvolvimento contante (costumam lançar uma nova versão a cada 4 ou 6 meses) e é bem amparado pela comunidade linux (KDE, por exemplo), mas, não posso afirmar que é amplamente utilizada para mobile pois esse suporte foi iniciado há pouco tempo.

**Considerações:**

A principal vantagem nesse framework é facilidade e velocidade de desenvolvimento. A linguagem [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) torna fácil desenvolver interfaces que nativamente dariam bastante trabalho. O funcionamento entre Android, iOS e Windows Phone é bem próximo, diferenciado apenas em questões realmente específicas dos sistemas.

Falando agora de desvantagens:

1. Quando há necessidade de utilizar recursos nativos dos sistemas, a comunicação entre o código Qt e o código nativo é complicado. E, como o suporte a mobile é recente, não há muitos exemplos na internet.
2. As bibliotecas do Qt são muito grandes. Os aplicativos facilmente pesarão 10MB, o que pode ser ruim para alguns usuários.
3. Nem todos os módulos estão prontos. Até última vez que verifiquei o módulo de bluetooth, por exemplo, não era suportado por todas as plataformas. Na versão 5.3 (que sai nas próximas semanas) o suporte a Android e iOS estará praticamente completo, mas para Windows Phone, alguns módulos só estarão disponíveis na versão 5.4.
4. Os Apps desenvolvidos no Qt não terão o [look and feel](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look_and_Feel) padrão do sistema (não por enquanto). O que pode ser bom e ruim (dependendo que você deseja fazer).

**[Exemplos](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Digia)**

Comment: Lucas, muito obrigado por sua contribuição. Vou dar uma olhada boa no Qt mesmo. Não sabia que fazia deploy para mobile, interessante. O problema maior, de fato, é que fica muito grande o jogo.

Comment: @GarouDan Para jogos, como disse, eu consideraria outras soluções específicas. Posso citar alguns exemplos: cocos2dx, Unity, corona. A vantagem dessas é que elas são feitas para isso e você terá muitas funções e ferramentas já preparadas para lidar com sprites, sons, partículas, física e etc. Além de serem otimizadas para isso.

Comment: Muito interessante. Vou dar uma olhada nelas, porque no momento estou querendo para jogos mesmo.

Comment: @GarouDan Hoje me deparei com esse: http://v-play.net/ pode te interessar.